# Pytorch Lightning Loaded Model Gives Different Results Each Time

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, pytorch-lightning

I have a U-Net architecture and when I train the model and print out some results without loading it, the model gives good results but when I load the model checkpoint file and try to make predictions it predicts random noise, even worse it gives different predictions for each run with the same test set

Here is my code

```
model.py https://pastecode.io/s/nhjznzxc
train.py https://pastecode.io/s/umjqprb3
pred.py https://pastecode.io/s/m9zkpwk5
```

Answer (score 1):

`load_from_checkpoint()` is not an inner function, you need to assign it to `model` variable. Otherwise, you just used a randomly initialized model which results in different results.

```
model = model.load_from_checkpoint('Model/last.ckpt', in_channels=1, out_channels=N_CLASSES, features=[16, 32, 64, 128, 192, 256], batch_size=16)
```

I will recommend using `pytorch_lightning.seed_everything(seed)` to control random seeds.

Comment: Why model inference still needs randomizing weights?

Comment: No, you don't. I brought up `seed_everything()` because the op mentioned arbitrary predictions which may come from different randomly initialized models in the provided scripts.